# Subprograma con 2 cadenas de texto, una que se almacene desde el codigo y otra que la pida por teclado

Tags: c

Necesito crear un subprograma en C que almacene y muestre dos cadenas de texto, una se tiene que almacenar desde el codigo y otra la tiene que solicitar por teclado. Esas cadenas las tengo que utilizar luego para otros subprogramas.
Tengo hecho esto pero al iniciarlo no me muestra la cadena 1 y la cadena 2 no acepta espacios. ¿Una ayudita?

```
void inicializarCadenas(){
    char c1[40] = "Hola mundo";
    printf("La cadena c1 es: ", c1);
    char c2[40];
    printf("\nIntroduzca la cadena c2: ");
    scanf("%s", &c2);
    printf("La cadena c2 es: ", c2);
}
```

Comment: La cadena c1 no se muestra porque no lo has indicado con %s en el primer parámetro de printf. Para la cadena c2, lo ideal es que uses como mínimo fgets en lugar de scanf, que no solo te va a aceptar los espacios en blanco, sino que te va a prevenir problemas de desbordamiento del buffer.

Answer (score 0):

La opción de `scanf` con `%s` no sirve para leer líneas ya que, como has visto, deja de leer al encontrarse el primer separador, que por defecto puede ser:

- espacio
- tabulador
- salto de linea

Para leer una línea desde `stdin` puedes usar `getline`:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t lineSize = 0;
lineSize = getline(&line, &len, stdin);

printf("%s", line);

free(line); // <<--- importante
```

No hay que olvidar que `getline` gestiona memoria dinámica, por lo que hay que acordarse de liberar dicha memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria.

`getline` tiene tantos parámetros porque puede aceptar un array previamente reservado, en caso de que la nueva cadena no entre en el array, `getline` modificará el tamaño de la reserva para adaptarlo a las necesidades.

Otra opción, más insegura, es usar `gets`:

```
char line[200];
gets(line);
printf("%s", line);
```

El problema que tienes aquí es que `gets` no recibe cuántos caracteres entran en `line`, luego no puede prevenir desbordamiento de buffer.

La opción segura en este caso es `fgets`:

```
char line[200];
fgets(line, 200, stdin);
printf("%s", line);
```

Como ves, `fgets` recibe como argumento el tamaño del array. En este caso no intentará redimensionarlo bajo ninguna circunstancia. Lo que hace `fgets` cuando se alcanza el límite indicado es, simplemente, dejar de almacenar caracteres en el array.